# while loop:::iterate line only 1 time,while value iterate when condition satisfied

Tags: python

In the given code i have a while loop for printing Fibonacci series of number,In this i have a print line

```
print(f'''The Fibonacci series of number "{last_number}" is"{y}.''')
```

I want this line to print only once and only value of y is added after it.The output should be he Fibonacci series of number "50" is 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34.

```
while True:
            while True:
                        try:
                            last_number = int(input('\nEnter last number :'))
                        except ValueError:
                            print("\nPlease enter only number")
                        else:
                            break
            x,y=0,1
            while y<last_number:
                print(f'''The Fibonacci series of number "{last_number}" is"{y}.''')
                x,y=y,x+y
            while True:
                        Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                        Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                        if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                            print("\nPlease select correct option")
                        else:
                            break


            if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                continue
            else:
                if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                    print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                    input()
                    break
```

Comment: Just move it out to after the while loop?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: i did moved it out of while loop but in only gives 55 as output of y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to insert the values in a list and then get the values out of list as you have integers value in list you need to make it a string before getting the values out of list.

```
    while True:
                while True:
                            try:
                                last_number = int(input('\nEnter last number :'))
                            except ValueError:
                                print("\nPlease enter only number")
                            else:
                                break
                x,y=0,1
                z=[]
                while y<last_number:
                    z.append(y)
                    x,y=y,x+y
                a=str(z)[1:-1]
                print(f'''The Fibonacci series of number "{last_number}" is {a}.''')
                while True:
                            Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                            Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                            if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                                print("\nPlease select correct option")
                            else:
                                break


                if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                    continue
                else:
                    if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                        print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                        input()
                        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the print before the loop and then create a list and with append add the serie.
Afterwards you can just print the list and it will look the same
Another method is to create the list before the print and then print the list with the sentence you entered